# Writing to second table in database for Android Application

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am (and have been for a while) working on an android project that will serve as a very basic class schedule app. So far, I have the following working: add courses to database, remove courses from database, display courses with location and subject on a list, open up an "assignments" menu to create an assignment for a course.

The problem is that when I attempt to click the save button on the assignment creation menu, it just doesn't add the assignment to the list.

The assignment list is a second table within the "courses" database (labeled lunchlist.db). Attached below are the three classes that are responsible for handling the assignments.

Assignment List:

```
public class AssList extends ListActivity {
    public final static String ID_EXTRA = "apt.tutorial._ID";
    Cursor model = null;
    AssAdapter adapter = null;
    AssHelper helper = null;
    SharedPreferences prefs = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ass);

        helper = new AssHelper(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        helper.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView list, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent i = new Intent(AssList.this, AssForm.class);

        i.putExtra(ID_EXTRA, String.valueOf(id));
        startActivity(i);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        new MenuInflater(this).inflate(R.menu.ass_option, menu);

        return (super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.add_ass) {
            startActivity(new Intent(AssList.this, AssForm.class));

            return (true);
        }

        return (super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
    }

    public void initList() {
        if (model != null) {
            stopManagingCursor(model);
            model.close();
        }

        model = helper.getAll(prefs.getString("sort_order", "name"));
        startManagingCursor(model);
        adapter = new AssAdapter(model);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener prefListener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPrefs,
                String key) {
            if (key.equals("sort_order")) {
                initList();
            }
        }
    };

    class AssAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
        AssAdapter(Cursor c) {
            super(AssList.this, c);
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(View row, Context ctxt, Cursor c) {
            AssHolder holder = (AssHolder) row.getTag();

            holder.populateFrom(c, helper);
        }

        @Override
        public View newView(Context ctxt, Cursor c, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
            AssHolder holder = new AssHolder(row);

            row.setTag(holder);

            return (row);
        }
    }

    static class AssHolder {
        private TextView name = null;
        private TextView address = null;
        private ImageView icon = null;

        AssHolder(View row) {
            name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.title);
            address = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.address);
            icon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        }

        void populateFrom(Cursor c, AssHelper helper) {
            name.setText(helper.getName(c));
            address.setText(helper.getUrgency(c));

            if (helper.getUrgency(c).equals("normal")) {
                icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.eg);
            } else if (helper.getUrgency(c).equals("pending")) {
                icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ey);
            } else {
                icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.er);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Assignment Form:

```
public class AssForm extends Activity {
    EditText name = null;
    RadioGroup types = null;
    AssHelper helper = null;
    String AssId = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ass_edit);

        helper = new AssHelper(this);

        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.assname);
        types = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.urge);

        Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save_ass);
        Button del = (Button) findViewById(R.id.del_ass);
        save.setOnClickListener(onSave);
        del.setOnClickListener(onDel);

        AssId = getIntent().getStringExtra(AssList.ID_EXTRA);

        if (AssId != null) {
            load();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        helper.close();
    }

    private void load() {
        Cursor c = helper.getById(AssId);

        c.moveToFirst();
        name.setText(helper.getName(c));

        if (helper.getUrgency(c).equals("normal")) {
            types.check(R.id.normal);
        } else if (helper.getUrgency(c).equals("pending")) {
            types.check(R.id.pending);
        } else {
            types.check(R.id.due);
        }

        c.close();
    }

    private View.OnClickListener onSave = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String type = null;

            switch (types.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
            case R.id.normal:
                type = "normal";
                break;
            case R.id.pending:
                type = "pending";
                break;
            case R.id.due:
                type = "due";
                break;
            }

            if (AssId == null) {
                helper.insert(name.getText().toString(), type);
            } else {
                helper.update(AssId, name.getText().toString(), type);
            }

            finish();
        }
    };

    private View.OnClickListener onDel = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            helper.deleteValue(name.getText().toString());

            finish();
        }
    };
}
```

Assignment Helper:

```
class AssHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "lunchlist.db";
    private static final int SCHEMA_VERSION = 1;

    public AssHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, SCHEMA_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE assignments (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, assname TEXT, urge TEXT);");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // no-op, since will not be called until 2nd schema
        // version exists
    }

    public Cursor getAll(String orderBy) {
        return (getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(
                "SELECT _id, assname, urge FROM assignments ORDER BY "
                        + orderBy, null));
    }

    public Cursor getById(String id) {
        String[] args = { id };

        return (getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(
                "SELECT _id, assname, urge FROM assignments WHERE _ID=?",
                args));
    }

    public void insert(String name, String type) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put("assname", name);
        cv.put("urge", type);

        getWritableDatabase().insert("assignments", "assname", cv);
    }

    public void deleteValue(String value) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

        String whereClause = "assname" + "=?";
        String[] whereArgs = new String[] { String.valueOf(value) };
        db.delete("assignments", whereClause, whereArgs);
        db.close();
    }

    public void update(String id, String name, String type) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        String[] args = { id };

        cv.put("assname", name);
        cv.put("urge", type);

        getWritableDatabase().update("assignments", cv, "_ID=?", args);
    }

    public String getName(Cursor c) {
        return (c.getString(1));
    }

    public String getUrgency(Cursor c) {
        return (c.getString(2));
    }
}
```

I know it is a lot to read through, however I am really stuck on this final part to my project. These three classes are (for all intents and purposes) almost identical to the three for adding courses. The only differences are that the variable names are changed and that the class references are switched to match the assignment classes. Any help or criticism is greatly welcomed. Thank you in advance for taking the time to read through my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after you save your edits or entries to the database, you need to reload your cursor and call `notifydatasetchanged()` on your listview to tell it to refresh. Since the submit form and listview are in different activities, and one must be on top of the other, i'd think the most straight-forward way is to do these on the `OnResume()` method of your list-activity, perhaps instigated with a conditional intent to avoid useless refreshing. Even more blunt is to simply make sure the listactivity is always "finished" when out of view so that each time you see it is a new instance and thus reset cursor.

a good way to check that the above is correct, is to close out the app entirely and see if your edits or entries come up on the app restart.

---

**EDIT:** well your question was irking my curiosity a bit and eventually i buckled and just ran the full code myself and tested this solution myself. can't believe we all missed it, but the issue wasn't that that things weren't adding to your listview, but that your listview wasn't showing at all. The problem was that your listview was never hooked up to the cursor adapter. here's all you need:

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ass);
        helper = new AssHelper(this);        
        loadListview();      
    }   

    private void loadListview() {
        Cursor c = helper.getAll("urge");
        mAdapter = new AssAdapter(c);
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
```

I made a seperate method of a mere 3 lines of code, cause your listview still in fact does need to be refreshed upon returning to the activity. you might not want to do it this way but cause i'm lazy, i chose to do it in the following way:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    loadListview();
}
```

My personal issue with this is that the first instance of the cursor never gets the chance to be closed which is a bit inelegant imo. btw, this has nothing to do with the issue, but your code makes quite a bit of use of deprecated methods (ex. deprecated cursor constructor, `startManagingCursor`...), you might or might not want to consider revising these parts. and also remember to close your cursors and database when you're done.

Comment: When I close the program fully, the assignments do not appear on the list. Does that mean that a different solution is required? Sorry for the slow reply, I have been using my school's network, due to power loss in my area.

Comment: i revised my post, i apologize for the mistake.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I appreciate you going through my amateurish code.

Comment: I'm actually now getting a force close when I click the assignments button. When I comment out the loadListview(); in the onCreate() method, the force close stops, however the program of course operates as it did before.

Comment: 11-07 11:04:28.971: E/AndroidRuntime(354): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-07 11:04:28.971: E/AndroidRuntime(354): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{apt.tutorial/apt.tutorial.AssList}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: assignments: , while compiling: SELECT _id, assname, urge FROM assignments ORDER BY urge
It seems to be saying that there is no such table "assignments". I'm a bit confused, as I can see in my code where I created that table.

Comment: Did you make any changes to the table declaration? Try uninstalling the app in the emulator and running again

Comment: I just tried re installing the app, but with no luck. Did you just declare AssAdapter mAdapter = null; at the top of the class, with the other global objects?

Comment: Also, may I ask what the getAll() method is? Is it supposed to be user defined, because my AssHelper class does not have that method.

Comment: i got it right from your assignment helper class. it's the third method, the public cursor o.o?  allright, i just re-made your app a second time. i have two identical apps on my emulator, and none give any issue. i made no changes to the code above, perhaps there's some discrepancy with the code above and yours - different spellings maybe? And yes, i kept all the null assignments.

Comment: I'm so stumped. Even after retyping everything I'm still getting a force close every time I click on the Assignments button. Any ideas what could be causing it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19242/discussion-between-mango-and-l337man)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you could wrap your database in a ContentProvider and then use CursorLoader to manage the Cursor. CursorLoader runs on a background thread (yay!) and automatically reloads the Cursor when its underlying data changes.

A ContentProvider provides a bit of overhead, but it hides a lot of messy database stuff that you otherwise have to handle on your own. While the documentation says that you don't *have* to use a content provider to use a database, a content provider is sometimes better. It's mostly better because it saves *your* time. I suspect that the performance of most apps is on the whole unaffected by using a content provider.

Comment: How and where would I implement a ContentProvider? I haven't had any experience with it.